# Using C++ to access Documents folder on iOS

Tags: c++, ios

I'm wondering if there is a way to get a reference to the Documents folder on iOS using just C++ (i.e. WITHOUT using ANY code in Objective-C; this because it is a framework implemented only in C++ that can be add as a library in a iOS project).

Please, if it is possible, provide code in your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With code below I able to access cache folder in my app. I think, documents folder in "/Library/Documents", or somewere else.

```
char *home = getenv("HOME");
char *subdir = "/Library/Caches/subdir";
```

`home` + `subdir` = full path

Next, with full path, you can do usual things to read/write in C++

Comment: You can also do this for the Documents folder. Simply `home` + `/Documents`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have access to the plain Unix APIs. See Apples [iOS manpages here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/).

Answer (score 1):

Get the path (using Cocoa APIs), then convert it to a C++ string compatible representation using and API such as: `CFStringGetFileSystemRepresentation`,  `CFURLGetFileSystemRepresentation`, or `-[NSString fileSystemRepresentation]`.

Something like:

```
// you may need to wrap this in an autorelease pool
NSArray * paths(NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES));
const char* const path([[paths objectAtIndex:0] fileSystemRepresentation]);
if (0 == fsrep) {
  uh-oh
}
const std::string result(path);
```

Then you can simply put that in its own ObjC++ translation and return `result` from the function (which would be visible to the rest of your C++ sources).