# C interface to get documents folder on iOS

Tags: c++, iphone, ios, c

Now I use:

```
[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
```

to get Documents folder on iOS, but I would like to have C interface to keep file type as C/C++ instead of Objective-C/C++.

Is it possible to get Documents path on iOS using only C functions?

EDIT: duplicate of [Using C++ to access Documents folder on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469342/using-c-to-access-documents-folder-on-ios)

```
char *home = getenv("HOME");
```

return application folder. Removing "/private" and adding "/Documents" should work.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469342/using-c-to-access-documents-folder-on-ios

Comment: C or C++? There are not the same

Comment: Almost all C function will be C++ compatible. As davecom stated, this is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469342/using-c-to-access-documents-folder-on-ios and the answers presented there fixed my problem.