# Get iPhone directory path in C++

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c++

I am using a C++ library from an Objective-C layer. I want to be able to access this path, or at least it's container identifying string, directly in the C++ library.

(NB: In production we are able to pass the identifier from the Objective-C layer, but this is to try and get the path directly in CI)

For example, if I get the `NSDocumentDirectory` path in Objective-C, the path is easy:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/93C788E8-3F76-4DD2-BC5F-7980BE9970C7/Documents
```

I could strip out the GUID (`93C788E8-3F76-4DD2-BC5F-7980BE9970C7`) from this path and pass it, but I need to be able to generate it purely in C++. Our CI is running our unit test suite directly on a device instead of a simulator. I know that this is basically a unix command, but I've spent my morning snooping around, and coming up empty. Any ideas where to look?

Comment: I don't really get the relation between your program and this path...or what your question is. Do you just want to know how to extract the Uuid/GUID from the path in C++?

Comment: Yes @SimonKraemer that is exactly what I'd like to do, as the rest of the path is standard.

Comment: And to clarify, I am not asking how to parse a string in C++ :) I need to get the GUID from the system while not leaving a C++ codebase.

Comment: So your question is how to either get the GUID or the documents path so you can extract the GUID from there?

Comment: Yes. If the endgame leaves me with the GUID in some capacity, my job is done :)

Comment: Have you already tried `getenv("HOME");`? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469342/using-c-to-access-documents-folder-on-ios

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103199/discussion-between-dokun1-and-simon-kraemer).

Comment: Are you sure you need this data? What is its meaning in the test anyway? Why can't the data be provided via some mock object?

Comment: @Eiko yes because we went through the trouble of setting up a physical device to run our tests, and this gives us a chance to ensure our tests pass in as close an environment to prod as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getenv("HOME");` to get the path to your application's directory.

Taking your example into account this should return `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/93C788E8-3F76-4DD2-BC5F-7980BE9970C7/`.

Then you can extract the GUID from this path.

The idea to this was taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/17284816/4181011