# iOS - Get a writable path in C++

Tags: c++, ios, native, audioqueue

I'm writing a sound recorder for iOS in native C++ and i cannot use the Foundation API.

I need something like this:

```
recordFilePath = 
(CFStringRef)[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"recordedFile.caf"];
```

To get a writable path on the iPhone.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you explain why you can't use the Foundation API if its meant to run on an iPhone ?

Comment: Because it has to compile with Cocos2d-x.

Comment: I think this is what i was looking for, if still valid:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469342/using-c-to-access-documents-folder-on-ios

Comment: Have you heard about Objective-C++ ? You can mix Objective-C (so Foundation) with C++ (Cocos2d-x) by setting you file an .mm extension. In your case you could just let some utility function like resourcePath() in this .mm file and use them in cpp without any problem. Otherwise you can still use CoreFoundation which is plain C. Foundation is barely an Objective-C wrapper (with some additions) of CoreFoundation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i knew about it. But as i said, the C++ class must be independent and should not call any external function from a .mm -
I think if i use getenv("HOME") i could achieve what i wanted without any Foundation reference. However, thanks for the code, you are very kind.

Comment: I don't know about Cocos2d-x as I never used it, but my answer was based on this link: http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/foundation-framework-cant-use/6639; so I may say something wrong but there must be a way to do this... And I affirm this because cocos2d-x uses Foundation itself on iOS, which means both frameworks are compatible: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/b135d512d26fa5a72c328ee1b73024e9eb2b9bb9/cocos/platform/apple/CCThread-apple.mm

Comment: See my answer below. Thank you mate! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can, but speaking confidently this is a task for a client of mine and he requested no external functions or bridges or whatever involving Foundation in the core classes. So i had to built an audioqueue component without references to Foundation.

For the record, i succedeed just doing this:

```
        const char *home = getenv("HOME");
        const char *subdir = "/Documents/";
        const char *file = "recordedFile.caf";

        char *recPath = (char*)(calloc(strlen(home) + strlen(subdir) 
                              + strlen(file) + 1, sizeof(char)));

        strcpy(recPath, home); // copy string one into the result.
        strcat(recPath, subdir); // append string two to the result.
        strcat(recPath, file); // append string three to the result.

        //recordFilePath is our CFStringRef
        recordFilePath = CFStringCreateWithCString(0, recPath, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

        //recorder is an AQRecorder class like the one from SpeakHere code sample
          recorder->StartRecord(recordFilePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

After commenting OP, an example using Objective-C++:

Utils.hpp:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

std::string temporaryFilePath(const std::string &filename)
```

Utils.mm:

```
#import "Utils.hpp"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

std::string temporaryFilePath(const std::string &filename)
{
    NSString *filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:filename.c_str()]];
    const char *rawFilePath = [filePath UTF8String];
    return rawFilePath;
}
```

WhereverYouWant.cpp:

```
#include "Utils.hpp"

...

std::string recordFilePath = temporaryFilePath("recordedFile.caf");
```